# Convert PyCharm ok script to standalone

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, optparse, debian-jessie

I have got simple pcov.py script in PyCharm using optparse

```
from optparse import OptionParser
```

As I understand PyCharm has every project in its own virtual environment. My package has the following packages installed (Project: pcov.py > Project interpreter):

- argparse
- pip
- setuptools
- wheel
- wsgiref

My project works fine within PyCharm in respect to parsing command line options:

```
parser = OptionParser(usage=usage)
...
parser.add_option("-z", action="store_true", dest="clean_build",
                  help="Clean all intermediate files")
...
```

Sadly, it doesn't when I try to run it standalone (from the command line) saying to me incomprenesible:

```
./pcov.py -z

[the pcov.py hangs here and I had to kill it with Ctrl-C]

from: can't read /var/mail/optparse
./pcov.py: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token ('
./pcov.py: line 9: def pselect(choices):'
```

Note that PyCharm never complains of no syntax errors and PyCharm handles -z command line option nicely.

I thought at first that I have to install some more package `globally', but I didn't find`optparse' python package (pip search optparse) showed me no exact match.

Thus my questions:

1) What packages I have to install (pip install ) to make my pcov.py script running as it does under PyCharm ?

2) Is there an automated way 'to deliver' the PyCharm working script as a standalone Python script?

Using PyCharm CE 2017.0, Debian 8 jessie, python 2.7

Comment: How have you set project interpreter?

Comment: In PyCharm 
Preferences > Project : pcov.py > Project interpreter
selected Show all  , and selected /usr/bin/python

Comment: Then it's your system interpreter, not one in virtual environment. I can describe in some detail how to configure it in a few moments. Meanwhile you can try to create a virtual environment with pycharm yourself.

Comment: I thought the interpreter is the same for all PyCharm projects (in my case it is Python 2 or Python 3). Each virtual environments has their own set of installed packages in that respect they differ

Comment: My hunch was that my script would work as good standalone as it now does within PyCharm as soon as I make my `global' environment similar to that of PyCharm.

Comment: I ashamed! I have just added
#!/usr/bin/env python
at the beginning of my script and it solved the problem.